# hammer js and jquery-ui draggable issue in IE 7 - 8

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, hammer.js

I am using Hammer js and jQuery ui draggable. When dragging an element in IE 7 - 8 the draggable element freezes in the next moment after draggable is executed. Even though I am using the plugins for different purposes they are causing an issue. Perhaps it's something about the way the Hammer js event is bound in IE 7 - 8.

If I comment out the Hammer js event listener it'll work absolutely fine.

**Hammer js:**

```
shortlistedProducts.hammer()
                .on('swipe', function (e) {
                    var gestureDirection = e.gesture.direction,
                        productLength = shortList.find('.product').length,
                        nextSlide = (currentThumb + productsInLine) >= productLength ? productLength : currentThumb + productsInLine,
                        prevSlide = (currentThumb - productsInLine) < 0 ? null : currentThumb - productsInLine;


                    if (gestureDirection === 'left') {

                        thisObj.slideAnimationHandler("right", nextSlide === productLength, nextSlide);

                    } else if (gestureDirection === 'right') {

                        thisObj.slideAnimationHandler("left", prevSlide === null, prevSlide);

                    }

                });
```

**jQuery:**

```
product.draggable({
                appendTo: 'body',
                helper: 'clone',
                zIndex: 10010,
                scroll: false
            });

            productContainer.droppable({
                tolerance: 'touch',
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                activate: function (event, ui) {

                    if (!shortList.hasClass('visible')) {
                        shortList.animate({ 'bottom': 0 }).removeClass('preview').addClass('visible');
                    }

                },
                deactivate: function (event, ui) {

                    if (!shortlistedProducts.find('.product').length) {
                        shortList.animate({ 'bottom': '-' + shortList.outerHeight() }).removeClass('visible');
                    }
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var target = jQuery(this).find('.products'),
                        targetLength = target.children('.product').length;

                    thisObj.shortListHandler(ui.draggable, 'add');

                    thisObj.productCountHandler();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with hammer.js. Once I commented out hammer.js function it worked well, so I thought that if I manage to stop hammer.js from executing on IE 7-8 the problem would be solved. In fact gestures won't be necessary on IE 7-8 as there are no touch devices with IE 7-8 on board. The solution to my problem was to execute hammer.js function only if a device supports gesture, which in case of IE 7-8 is false.

```
'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0
```